# PT9 Possible Bug?

Tags: pro-tools-9, bugs, clock

Anyone have an issue in Pro Tools 9, running on Snow Leopard, where the DAW consistently puts out a a problem detected report every 5-10 minutes and the temporary fix is to increase or decrease the buffer size?

"Problem detected with audio clock. Check that your clock source and sample rate are correct."

Under clock Source it says "See Control Panel" - is that Audio Midi Setup or Sound Options under the OSX preferences? Or something different?

Thanks!

C3

Comment: Actually, I think I fixed it. - Update soon.

Comment: How did you fix the problem? I can't seem to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

It was a clock problem - Nevermind!